# how to group form-group controls and disable to unselected radio button group?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

I have a group of controls in form-group- **radio button, label and kendo dateTime picker**.

On selecting one group, the group items should be disabled.

Below is the code for the 3 form groups:

```
<!-- group 1 -->
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" name="maintenanceGroup" id="dateTimepicker1" value="setDate" data-bind="checked: maintenanceOption"/>
     <label style="display: inline;  margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 10px" for="datetimepicker1">Run the maintenance scheduled </label>
        <input class='input-group date' id='kendodatetimepicker' data-bind=" kendoDateTimePicker: {value: maintenanceDateTime , format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt', parseFormats: ['yyyy-MM-ddhh:mm tt']}" />
</div>


<!-- group 2 -->
 <div class="form-group">
     <input type="radio" name="maintenanceGroup" id="dateTimepicker2" value="postponeDate"  data-bind="checked: maintenanceOption"/>
     <label style="display: inline; margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 10px" for="dateTimepicker2">Postpone maintenance for</label>
     <input class='input-group date' id='postponeDatetimepicker' 
            data-bind="kendoDateTimePicker: {value: postponeMaintenanceDateTime , format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt', parseFormats: ['yyyy-MM-ddhh:mm tt']}" />
</div>


<!-- group 3 -->
<div class="form-group">
     <input type="radio" name="maintenanceGroup" id="dateTimepicker3" value="skipDate" data-bind="checked: maintenanceOption"/>
     <label for="dateTimepicker3">Skip scheduled maintenance. The next scheduled maintenance is for </label>
     <span id="skipMaintenance" data-bind="text: skippedMaintenanceTime"></span>
</div>
```

Suppose on selecting the first radio button, all the controls in the next two form group elements should be disabled.

Here is the fiddle link for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/T3zge/73/

can anyone help me with the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Listen for click events on each radio button, and disable/enable whichever controls you need in the handler:

```
$('#dateTimepicker1').click(function(e){
    $('#postponeDatetimepicker').data('kendoDateTimePicker').enable(false);
    $('#kendodatetimepicker').data('kendoDateTimePicker').enable(true);
});

$('#dateTimepicker2').click(function(e){
    $('#kendodatetimepicker').data('kendoDateTimePicker').enable(false);
    $('#postponeDatetimepicker').data('kendoDateTimePicker').enable(true);
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/RH7Nn/2/).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can this be done with knockout binding? is there any knockout property which enables or disables controls?  I m trying to reduce the usage of jquery.

Comment: @user2439903 knockout has an 'enable' and 'disable' binding that might work - [see this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html)

Comment: Thanks, but i couldn't get it working in the fiddle.